# Flex/Actionscript - "class" XML attribute name error when parsing to ArrayCollection

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am trying to convert XML response event to ArrayCollection using Flex 4 and Actionscript.

The problem being that i don't have control on the output XML HTTP response and one of the attributes is names 'class' so, I get an error trying to access the object

Actionscript code:

```
protected var products:ArrayCollection;

protected function service_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    products = event.result.oxip.response.class.type.market; 
}
```

Comment: Completely unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

When a property name is a [reserved word](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9b.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6e) you can only access them using [array bracket access](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#array_access). For example:

```
products = event.result.oxip.response["class"].type.market;
```